# IE This page cannot be displayed but Chrome will work

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, iis-6

This is my set up.
IIS 6 running on Windows Server 2003 64 bit 4GB RAM
Local client, Windows 7. IE11 and Chrome.
Single Test.HTML page in Default Site at the root.

I get "This page cannot be displayed" when trying to open the page in IE11 98% of the time. However Chrome works 100% every single time. Chrome also writes to the WWW Log but when IE can't display the page nothing is written to the log.

Everything works fine on the Web Server via IE8 also.

This has been a huge problem for a long time so I'm hoping that someone will see this and have a good idea what the problem might be.

Comment: Hi Dave, Is this your home or office setup? For home developer use, select Tools>Compatibility View Settings and add the domain of your webserver (on the 2003) to the IE list... this forces IE11 to emulate IE7...Probably the web page that you are trying to load contains a <object> tag for a Shockwave Flash element. which is blocked by IE. You should remove the clsid and codebase attributes on those elements and add the data and type attributes.... this will swap over to the Adobe Flash ActiveX control.

Comment: Please see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/browser/dn818438.aspx?f=255 - Blocked out of Date ActiveX Controls.

Comment: Rob, it's an office set-up and IE is locked down (I will have an unlocked version to test in a couple days time!). I tried the compatibility and it made no difference. The web page I'm trying to load its just plain HTML "Hello World", also that TechNet link is broken. Thanks all the same. Guess I will Test on Friday and see what I can find.